# Is there a geometric interpretation to the orientation of the spin vector of a spin $1$ atom after passing through a Stern-Gerlach magnetic filter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

When a spin $\frac{1}{2}$ atom passes through a Stern-Gerlach magnetic filter, the atom's spin vector is aligned to be in either the upper hemisphere or the lower hemisphere. This makes good sense geometrically because after passing through the filter we know that the vector has either a $+z$ or $-z$ component.

In the case of a spin $1$ atom passing through a Stern-Gerlach magnetic filter is there a similar geometric reasoning to the orientation of the spin vector? Since the spin along the $z$ axis for example could be either $1, 0, \text{or} -1$ after passing through the filter, in what regions could the spin vector be? Up, down, and not up or down? Does that mean it comes out in one upper hemisphere, one lower hemisphere, and then the $XY$ plane?

Comment: Which vector are you talking about? A complex vector in a Hilbert Space? If so, then it becomes aligned with a complex Hilbert state vector in one of the eigenspaces of the spin "component " operator. Or for spin 1/2 any complex Hilbert state vector is associated with the positive eigenvalue of $n_x\hat\sigma_x+n_y\hat\sigma_y+n_z\hat\sigma_z$ for some unique real unit vector $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ but I don't think there is a spin 1 corollary to that spin 1/2 trick.

Comment: @Timaeus yes, a complex vector in a Hilbert Space. Is your $n_x\hat{\sigma}_x...$ referring to the Pauli matrices?

Comment: The hat refers to the operator. A matrix requires a basis, if you choose the basis consisting of eigenvectors of $\hat\sigma_z$ then the operators can be *represented* by the Pauli matrices. But if you want complex vectors, then it's an uphill battle to make your question make any sense. Best of luck!